# On the way Hibernate maps a OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Let's take as example two entities `A` and `B`. Each `A` may have many associated `B`s. Each `B` is associated to exactly one `A`. I represent this relationship with Hibernate as follows:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "AId")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "AName", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BId") })
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();

}


@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "BId")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "BName")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BA")
    private A a;

}
```

When I generate the DB from this mapping, here's what I get:

- Table `A`.
- The join table `A_B` with 2 columns: `AId` and `BId`. `AId` and `BId` belong to the primary key. And since there is a `OneToMany` association from `A` to `B` (i.e. one `A` may have many associated `B`s, and one `B` is associated to exactly one `A`), a unique constraint is added on `BId`.
- Table `B` with columns including `BA` which is a `foreign` key referencing column `AId` of table `A`.

Concerning the `join table`,

- why does Hibernate map the `OneToMany` relationship this way?
- It could simply define the primary key as consisting of one column (`BId`) and the same rules would be enforced.
- Is there a reason why the mapping is done this way?
- What are the advantages/drawbacks of such a mapping?

I precise I'm using `Hibernate 4.1.6.Final`.

Comment: Creating tables with Hibernate is not good practice.

Comment: i have never use a joint column for one to many relations. you should normalize your database tables.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to map a bidirectional association: from A to B and from B to A.

> Concerning the join table, why does Hibernate map the OneToMany relationship this way?

Because you specified a join table. You can map a @OneToMany relation without it:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "AId", nullable = false)
private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();
```

or better as you have a bidirectional association:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")  
private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();
```

...

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)  
@JoinColumn(name = "AId", nullable = false)  
private A a;
```

Regarding

> Is there a reason why the mapping is done this way? What are the
>   advantages/drawbacks of such a mapping?

The mapping with the join table is useful when you have an optional one to many, if, for example B could have no A. It allows you to avoid a nullable AId column on the B table.